# Creating five rectangles with android UI canvas

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming and trying to create 5 rectangles(two on the right side of the screen and three on the left side of the screen) on android using the canvas drawRect method, but it only shows the top left rectangle only. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your help.

Here's my RectAngle class:

```
public class RectAngle extends View {
    public RectAngle(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        float x = getWidth();
        float y = getHeight();

        Paint topLeftRect = new Paint();
        Paint bottomLeftRect = new Paint();
        Paint topRightRect = new Paint();
        Paint midRightRect = new Paint();
        Paint bottomRightRect = new Paint();

        // Draw  the top left rectangle
        topLeftRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        //topLeftRect.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        topLeftRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF99"));
       // canvas.drawPaint(topLeftRect);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, x / 2, y / 2, topLeftRect);

        //Draw the bottom left rectangle

        bottomLeftRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        //bottomLeftRect.setColor(Color.WHITE);
       // canvas.drawPaint(bottomLeftRect);
        bottomLeftRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF99"));
        canvas.drawRect(0, y / 2, x / 2, 0, bottomLeftRect);

        //Draw the top tight rectangle

        topRightRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        //topRightRect.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        topRightRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6600"));
        //canvas.drawPaint(topRightRect);
        canvas.drawRect(x / 2, 0, 0, y / 3, topRightRect);

        // Draw the middle right rectangle

        midRightRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        //midRightRect.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        midRightRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#66FFFF"));
       // canvas.drawPaint(midRightRect);
        canvas.drawRect(x / 2, 0, 0, y / 3, midRightRect);

        //Draw the bottom right rectangle

        bottomRightRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        //bottomRightRect.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        bottomRightRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCC00"));
       // canvas.drawPaint(bottomRightRect);
        canvas.drawRect(x/2, y/3, 0, 0, bottomRightRect);




    }
}
```

Here's my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new RectAngle(this));
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

Here's an image of my emulator. I am only getting one colored rectangle and it should be 4 more on the bottom left, top right, middle right, and bottom right of the screen.

[Emulator image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phFTS.png)

Comment: what do you want to draw on canvas ? Add image with your question

Comment: Thanks USK. I added a screen shot of my emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class RectAngle extends View {
    public RectAngle(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        float x = getWidth();
        float y = getHeight();

        Paint topLeftRect = new Paint();
        Paint bottomLeftRect = new Paint();
        Paint topRightRect = new Paint();
        Paint midRightRect = new Paint();
        Paint bottomRightRect = new Paint();

        // Draw  the top left rectangle
        topLeftRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        //topLeftRect.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        topLeftRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF99"));
        // canvas.drawPaint(topLeftRect);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, x / 2, y / 2, topLeftRect);

        //Draw the bottom left rectangle

        bottomLeftRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        //bottomLeftRect.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        // canvas.drawPaint(bottomLeftRect);
        bottomLeftRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF5599"));
        canvas.drawRect(0, y / 2, x / 2, y, bottomLeftRect);

        //Draw the top tight rectangle

        topRightRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        //topRightRect.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        topRightRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6600"));
        //canvas.drawPaint(topRightRect);
        canvas.drawRect(x / 2, 0, x, y / 3, topRightRect);

        // Draw the middle right rectangle

        midRightRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        //midRightRect.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        midRightRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#66FFFF"));
        // canvas.drawPaint(midRightRect);
        canvas.drawRect(x / 2, y/3, x, 2*y / 3, midRightRect);

        //Draw the bottom right rectangle

        bottomRightRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        //bottomRightRect.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        bottomRightRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCC00"));
        // canvas.drawPaint(bottomRightRect);
        canvas.drawRect(x/2, 2*y/3, x, y, bottomRightRect);




    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks USK. So, my coordinates were wrong. Thanks again.